# Firebase JavaScript how to display all the fields from the database to an HTML file

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an HTML template (a table specifically) and I would like to display all the firestore fields onto that table. How do I display firestore fields onto an HTML table

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>AR Level</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr id="data">
            <td>{{display title}}</td>
            <td>7{display author}}</td>
            <td>{{display level}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="button is-large is-fullwidth" id="Load_more">Load More Books</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("books").where("ItemType", "==", "Book").where("Program", "==", "AR")
    .get()
    .then(
        function(querySnapshot){
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                console.log(doc.data())
            })
        }
    )
```

Comment: What's your question?  If something isn't working with what you've shown, you will need to explain that.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question, please have a look and answer. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display all data from Firestore documents into html elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58855519/how-can-i-display-all-data-from-firestore-documents-into-html-elements)

Comment: I would like to complete this task with vanilla JS. Thank you for the help